# Interfaces - Implement abstract class methods

Tags: c#, oop

I'm not exactly sure how to ask this question, but basically what I want to do is access the abstract methods from IDog. Consider this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IDog dog = new Dog();
        dog.CatchFrisbee();
        dog.Speak("Bark") // error -> no implementation
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class Dog : Animal, IDog
    {
        public void CatchFrisbee()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dog Catching Frisbee");
        }
    }
    public abstract class Animal : IAnimal
    {
        public void Speak(string sayWhat)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sayWhat);
        }

        public void Die()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Longer Exists");
        }
    }
    public interface IDog
    {
        void CatchFrisbee();
    }
    public interface IAnimal
    {
        void Die();

        void Speak(string sayWhat);
    }
```

From my static void Main, I would like to be able to call dog.Speak() but I can't because it's not implemented in IDog. I know I can easily access Speak() from my derived classes but is it possible to access it from the implemenation or would that be a bad design?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that all `IDog`s are `IAnimal`s, declare `IDog` as implementing `IAnimal`

```
public interface IDog : IAnimal
```

Comment: @spender Thanks for the answer! I'm trying to become more disciplined in OOP practices and ran into an issue where I thought this would be beneficial. Is this something that is common because I was speaking to another developer and she asked why I wanted to do this as if it was a bad design. Thanks again!

Comment: Could you explain the principle that keeps `Dog` from inheriting `Speak()` since it `Dog` inherits `Animal` and `Animal` implements `Speak()`?

Comment: @pseudocoder because `IDog` isn't an `IAnimal`, `Dog` is. `Dog` can be cast to `IAnimal` or `Animal`, but `IAnimal` can't be cast to `IDog` or the other way around.

Comment: @RonBeyer OK I didn't see that the object was cast as `IDog` in `Main()`.  If it was cast as `Dog` would `Speak()` be available?

Comment: @pseudocoder Yes, it would be available if it was Dog

Comment: @pseudocoder yes, see the other answers, they are valid and work, but the architecture is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could perform a cast:

```
 ((Animal) dog).Speak("Bark");
```

Or take advantage of multiple interface inheritance:

```
public interface IDog : IAnimal
{
    void CatchFrisbee();
}
```